# Best Way to Pass variable to Woocommerce Product?

Tags: wordpress, session, woocommerce, hook

Here is the setup.

Customer fills out form of information for product specifications. This creates an entry in the db with a unique detailsID.

They then are taken to a product page, with many variables. They select the variable product and checkout.

Now in the db they have an order as well as a separate table with the details of their request.

What is the best way to connect the product they bought with the detailsID?

I would like to basically pass the detailsID to the product page, then add this detailsID to the product. Or add the orderID back into the details table.

I keep going around whether to add this as meta data, or use a session, or just do post order logic to add the order ID back into the details table.

I really just need to link the two once the order completes but am not sure the best method to do this. I am pretty new to Woocommerce so don't know a lot of the hooks yet.

Thank you so much for your suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of research and experimenting here is the method I have decided on. This seems to add the information in a variety of places to make it easy to track orders and to insure that the customer is getting the customized product they want.

[add custom data to woocommerce](https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/add-custom-data-woocommerce-order/)

I am using this method very close to how it is spelled out in this great article. This was really helpful for me being a woocommerce newb.